# How to bind content to individual div with promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

This plnkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/BjETLN7rvQ1hNRIm51zG?p=preview binds content to three divs within loop : `<div ng-repeat="id in ids">`

src :

```
{ "content" : "divContent" , "id" : "r1" }


<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div ng-controller="FetchCtrl">

<div ng-repeat="id in ids">
  <div ng-bind="content" ></div>
</div>

  </div> 

  </body>
</html>

// Example of how to call AngularJS $http service and
// process the returned promise

function FetchCtrl($scope, $http, $q) {

$scope.ids = ["r1", "r2", "r3"];

$scope.ids = $scope.ids.map(function(id){
    var getString = 'http-hello1.html?id='+id
    return $http.get(getString);
});

$scope.responses = [];

$q.all($scope.ids).then(function (values) {

      var counter = 0;
      values.map(function(m){
        $scope.content = m.data.content;
      })

    })


}
```

But how bind the result of each get request to the specific div ?

Could add id :  `<div id="{{id}}" ng-bind="content" ></div>` but this means I need to maintain a map of id,value entries ? Is there an idiomatic angularjs way to achieve this ?

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to fetch the HTML for the content?

Comment: @SeanLarkin the content of the div is mutable, so I will be re-invoking the code to get the div content every 10 seconds approx.

Comment: okay and then what is the purpose of the repeating? Is there always going to be 3 divs that need to have a specific order when you are dynamically fetching this content?

Comment: @SeanLarkin the content is dynamic so not always 3 divs. The div's will be rendered in the ordering of the loop but div content is updated at different times depending when each promise completes.

Comment: Do You plan to use bind-html-unsafe to show the loaded data? You could to use directy $scope.values = values and use values[$index] to get the result data

Comment: How are the rows/divs to be ordered? Is there a specific order that needs to be preserved or tracked?

Comment: @SeanLarkin the div elements are ordered as they are rendered from the loop : "<div ng-repeat="id in ids">"

Comment: Seems you are thinking about elements first....and not data model first. You don't bind to the div....you update the data model and let angular manage the dom. Not entirely clear exactly what you are needing or wanting to do here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I think a directive which dynamically fetches your content might be the answer for you.

```
angular.module('whateverYourModuleNameIs')
  .directive('dynamicRow', ['$http', '$interval', dynamicRowDirectiveFn]);

function dynamicRowDirectiveFn($http, $interval) {
  return {
    restrict: "EA", // I guess this is your choice how it renders
    scope: {
      id: '=' // you could grab the id and use it in your request
    },
    link: function linkFn(scope, element, attrs) {
      // Use $interval to repeatedly fetch content
      var repeatFetchWhichReturnsAPromise = $interval(fetchNewContent, 60000 * 15) //Executes function every x milliseconds.

      // Function that executes every time your interval occurs
      function fetchNewContent() {
        $http.get('urlYouNeedToFetch'+id).then(
          fetchNewContentSucess, fetchNewContentError
        );
      }

      function fetchNewContentSuccess(responseObject){
        //This sets your new HTML based on promise success
        element = responseObject.data; 
      }
      
      function fetchNewContentError(responseObject){
       //If its a bad request we probably either want to stop repeating
       // You can choose to do something else
       $interval.cancel(repeatFetchWhichReturnsAPromise);
      }          
    
    }
  }
}
```

So Instead of using `$q.all()`, Id recommend individually fetching the content based on a timer or specific trigger. The downside with `$q.all()` is that if one of the promises fail, they all fail.

In terms of knowing what specific URL the directive needs to fetch, you'll have to provide that information to the directive to be used.

This is a very rough example of a directive that you could write. The upside is that you don't have to worry about `bind-unsafe-html` or include `ngSanitize`, you are instead just resetting the value of `element` inside your `link` function.

As I don't have a better picture of what you are trying to accomplish from a feature/product standpoint I can only suggest this based on the info provided.