# Fetching and displaying reverse geocode from items in ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I pull a list of areas to display on a google maps from my database. I would also like to show the city closest to each area using [reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse) but cannot get it to work. 
I have some experience with AngularJS and promises and have searched Stackoverflow but cannot find any solution to this problem.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="area in vm.areas">
 <span>{{area.name}}</span>
 <span>Close to: </span> <span>{{vm.getCity(area)}}</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
vm.getCity = function(area){
 var center = getCenter(area.paths); 
 getAddress(center[0], center[1]).then(function(city){
   console.log(city);
   return city;
 })
}

function getAddress (latitude, longitude) {
  return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

      var method = 'GET';
      var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latitude + ',' + longitude + '&sensor=true';
      var async = true;

      request.open(method, url, async);
      request.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
              if (request.status == 200) {
                  var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                  var results = data.results;
                  var returnString = ""
                  for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
                    var types = results[i].types;
                    if(types[0] === 'locality'){
                      returnString = results[i].address_components[0].long_name;
                    }
                  }
                  resolve(returnString);
              }
              else {
                  reject(request.status);
              }
          }
      };
      request.send();
  });
};
```

I can see that the correct cities are showing up in the console but they are not visible in the view. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Managed to solve it using a directive instead, according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34953005/how-to-bind-content-to-individual-div-with-promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason why you're not using [Angular's `$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)? By not using it and making a custom HTTP call, Angular has no idea you're doing it. Therefore, when you get your data, Angular has no idea something has changed, and doesn't refresh the data or the view.
If you use Angular's `$http` service, you'll stay inside its ecosystem and make it aware of your changes.

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latitude + ',' + longitude + '&sensor=true'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // var data = ......
 }, function errorCallback(response) {

});
```

Comment: This indeed makes angular recognize the http-request, thanks! However the issue now is that when the page is rendered the function is called which makes the value change => page gets re-rendered again and stuck in a loop. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Why is the page re-rendered? You mean, reloaded? What's triggering that? I can see nothing in your code that reloads the page.

Comment: Maybe this isnt whats happening, byt i'm getting the "10 $digest() iterations reached error" and thought that was because the bound data is loaded repeatedly

Comment: Anyway, that's a different question, I think, maybe worth asking separately. Did I deserve some rep for resolving the `$http` issue? :)